# Laravel Orchid control panel fails to load javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

When loading Orchid, the following errors appear in the browser console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://somedomain.com/dashboard/resources/orchid/js/manifest.js?id=7db827d654313dce4250”.
login:21
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://somedomain.com/dashboard/resources/orchid/js/vendor.js?id=cd3591105503795d2f11”.
login:22
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://somedomain.com/dashboard/resources/orchid/js/orchid.js?id=ebdc2cac4cc1966d3383”.
login:23
```

```
http://somedomain.com/dashboard/resources/orchid/js/manifest.js?id=7db827d654313dce4250

Request method: Get

Status code: 404 Not Found
```

Comment: have you followed step by step this guide? https://orchid.software/en/docs/installation/

Comment: `php artisan orchid:link` fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

https://orchid.software/en/docs/installation/ > Publishing resources:

`php artisan orchid:link`

Answer (score 0):

I got `Command "orchid:link" is not defined.` error.

So I added

```
mix_url' => '/public' to config/app.php
```

it helped.